# Mediarecorder setCaptureRate not doing anything

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediaprojection

I have a screen recorder which i want the users to choose whether they want to record in timelapse mode or not.

The user can choose timelapse or not in the settings and im getting info about what setting they have picked.

However whenever i try to record in timelapse mode it does not work.

Here is the code where i try to record in timelapse:

```
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

    setVideoEncoder();

    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(8000000);

    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(RECORD_WIDTH, RECORD_HEIGHT);

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());

    mediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(1f);

    prepareRecorder();
```

It simply records video at a normal speed, thank you for any help!

I really need some help on this one, have tried googling and stuff with no result.

Comment: Does the camera you're working on support time lapse? Not all hardware will work alike.

Comment: @WindsurferOak it's the mediaprojection for lollipop, screen recording

Comment: Does CamcorderProfile.hasProfile return true for any of the CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_* profiles?

Comment: @WindsurferOak yes it returned true.

Comment: can you try setting the mediaRecorder.setCaptureRate to 0.1f? It should capture a frame every 10 seconds.

Comment: @WindsurferOak yeah i didnt really notice any differerence

Comment: @WindsurferOak wait do i need to call both setVideoFrameRate and setCaptureRate, can that be the problem? Cause now i am only calling setCaptureRate

Comment: It's possible that `setCaptureRate()` works by altering the rate at which the source (usually Camera) provides frames to the recorder. If that's the case, and the media projection code doesn't have a throttle, then this won't work. You can record at a lower rate by running the incoming frames through a SurfaceTexture and selectively dropping them, but that requires a bit of effort.